# Java / Spring model forms framework

Tags: java, spring, forms, spring-mvc, webforms

Is there any model/entity form abstraction library available i can use in Spring projects ?

I'm looking something like "[Django forms framework](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/)" or "[Symfony Forms](http://www.symfony-project.org/forms/1_4/en/01-Form-Creation)" in the Java/Spring world.

The basic idea is to simplify JPA entities form creation and the easier creation of multiform handling controllers.

Answer (score 3):

If i've understood you correctly you're after a way to bind an entity to a form (and allow a user to add/edit entities)? In which case theres no need for another framework Spring already does this really well. A quick example:

Our controller would look like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/addUser.html")
public class UserController {

  @Autowired
  private UserAccountService service;

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("userValidator")
  private Validator userValidator;

  @ModelAttribute("user")
  public User getBackingObject() {
    //This gets the object we're letting the user edit.
    //This can be any POJO so a JPA entity should be fine.
    //Note that we're creating an object here but we could 
    //just as easily fetch one we already have from a database/service etc
    return new User();
  }

  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String showForm() {
    //The form to present to the user
    return "/addUser";
  }

  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
  //note: here Spring has automatically bound the entries that have been input into the webform into the User param supplied here
  protected String onSubmit(User user, Errors errors, HttpServletRequest request) {

    userValidator.validate(user, errors);
    if (errors.hasErrors()) {
      //The validator showed up some errors so send the object back to let the user correct it
      return "/addUser";
    }

    //save our new user
    service.saveUser(user);

    //best practice is to redirect to another view to make sure the backing object is cleared
    return "redirect:/success.html";
  }

}
```

Then we can use spring form macros in our JSP to create the form:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Add a user</title>
</head>
<body>

<form:form commandName="user">
  <label for="firstname">first name</label> 
  <form:input path="firstname" /> <form:errors cssClass="errorText" path="firstname" />
  <label for="lastname">last name</label> 
  <form:input path="lastname" /> <form:errors cssClass="errorText" path="lastname" />
  <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i've seen examples like that but is there any helper to avoid implementing controller logic for all my entities, it looks like too much boilerplate code to me ?

Comment: Yea, as mentionedby surajz Spring Roo is a command line tool that can write a lot of the glue code for you. Its worth checking out especially if you're starting your project from scratch. Saying that, once you start writing controllers you begin to see that that little extra verbosity gives you a lot more power in what you're able to do with your code.

Comment: so to answer my initial question, no forms framework for spring is available. just a bunch of helper tools to create boilerplate code.

Answer (score 0):

I think spring roo does what you want to do.

Comment: yup, thats the closer form of a form library i could find available, (http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html/base-web.html) thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: np. There is also spring-data project that you can use. It might reduce your boilerplate jpa code. http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/1.0.0.M1/reference/html/. Hope this helps